# how to skip null entries from populating in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview which has some five textviews and one editText. I'm populating this listview from database but not all rows in database has records there are also null values, and in case of null values the listview shows null as you can see in the picture below. i want to get rid of this null. [image]

In case of null entry i want the show nothing in the textbox and textview.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just check the value if not null then only display in the listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a check in your adapter, before setting the value to your **EditText**.

```
if (myQuantity != null)
{
    editText.setText(String.valueOf(myQuantity));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. now when i scroll down the list the value in edit text is getting repeated below.

Comment: If quantity is not null, set the quantity, else set empty string. If that does not work, google for *Android listview recycling*, it's a common issue while scrolling, especially with EditText.

Comment: @Anita you should change to use RecyclerView, and in onViewDetachFromWindow of Adapter, you can keep the changed of edittext.

Comment: @Anita do a little research, and if it will not be working, ask another question (since it is a separate issue).

Answer (score 1):

In the `getView()` method  of listView adapter, apply the condition before set the value quality like:

```
if(quality.getText().toString() == null){

   quality.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To check value is null or not in database using this method Cursor.IsNull(Coulmn Index) and if Null set like("") instead of the actual null value or if value is not null set actual value